# CSS menu won't start at left

Tags: css

```css
body {
 width:960px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 margin:0 auto; 
 padding:0 auto;
 
}

ul {
 height:60px;
 width:100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 border: 1px solid white;
 
}

li {
 float:left;
 
}

ul a {
 color:black;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-size:20px;
 display:block;
 
}
 
ul li a {
 display:block;
 padding:20px 70px;
 line-height:1.0em;
 text-decoration:none;
}


ul a:hover {
 
 color:yellow; 
 background-color:black; 
 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type+ "text/css" href = "style.css"> 
  </head> <body background ="background.jpg"> 
  <div id="navigation"> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href = '#'>Home</a></li>
      <li><a href = '#'>Media Design</a></li>
      <li><a href = '#'>Informatie</a></li>
      <li><a href = '#'>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <center><img src="banner.png" alt="Media Design" height="540" width="960"></center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hi there, somehow when I run my website code (http://prntscr.com/8qsljg), the menu won't start at the very left. I tried like everything, but still I am stuck for this problem for a couple of hours.

Comment: The left of what? Have you used a CSS reset?

Comment: Can you paste your html as well?

Comment: <html>
<head>
 <link rel = "stylesheet" type+ "text/css" href = "style.css">
</head>
<body background ="background.jpg">
<div id="navigation">
 


 <ul>
  <li><a href = '#'>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href = '#'>Media Design</a></li>
  <li><a href = '#'>Informatie</a></li>
  <li><a href = '#'>Contact</a></li>
 </ul>
 
</div>
<center><img src="banner.png" alt="Media Design" height="540" width="960"></center>


</body>
</html>

Comment: You should have added it to your question. A little hint: I'd rather use CSS to give the body a background-image, inline styles aren't pretty. Oh and your images' sizes as well.

Comment: use padding:0px in ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty simple thing. You did not remove the `<ul>` of the menu under the navigation div.

What you need to do is just to include these lines in your CSS

```
div#navigation ul {
padding-left: 0px;}
```

Regards 
Nabeel

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the `padding` in your `ul` element:

```
ul {
   padding: 0px;
}
```